# Hiding the tab bar leaves a white space in iOS while the navigation to next page happens in react native

Tags: swift, react-native, react-navigation, uitabbar

I am working on an app where I am using react-native with iOS. So in one of my components I am navigating to the next component and sending an event to native to hide the tab bar at the same time. So while handling this event, I am hiding the tab bar which actually happens but leaving a white space at the bottom of the second component. Can anyone help in finding a solution for this?

```
tabBar.isHidden = true
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .bottom
```

This is the code that I am using but it doesn't have any effect other than replacing the tab bar with a white space.

Comment: facing same issue, please provide any solution if found...

Comment: facing the same issue